# C# Function that converts a string to a dictionary

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have a function that converts a string to a dictionary using the code below.  I need to add a 3rd delimiter that is essential a row or record delimiter.  Currently "," delimits [attribute,value] and "|" delimits each pair.  I can't figure out how to add the 3rd delimiter to separate the rows and add them to my dictionary.

```
                 var dict = feed.Split(',')
                   .Select(x => x.Split('|'))
                   .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

Comment: Show what the input looks like - we can't tell you how to parse it without seeing the input.

Comment: Dictionaries have keys and values - it's not at all clear what you've really got, or what you'd want the dictionary contents to be...

Comment: If you have a row that contains name/value pairs, how do you represent the rows?  Is it a List<> of Dictionary<> objects?

Comment: The input will look like this 'new_field1,value1| new_field2,value2/new_field1,value1| new_field2,value2.....'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With '/' as the row delimiter

```
var dict = x.Split('/').SelectMany(s => s.Split('|')).ToDictionary(t => t.Split(',')[0], t => t.Split(',')[1]);
```

Comment: This is the actual input string I tried your code with newline as the first delimiter and it's close but I get a "index out of bounds"     var dict = feed.Split('\n').SelectMany(s => s.Split('|')).ToDictionary(t => t.Split(',')[0], t => t.Split(',')[1]);

Comment: The input      "new_permanent|False,new_rcn|55426,new_Actionid|4f9d283c-cce7-e111-b08a-000c29c8eb0f,createdon|8/16/2012 6:00:23 PM,new_primary|True,new_id|1,new_processtype|Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue,ownerid|Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference,modifiedon|8/20/2012 5:07:25

Comment: This worked    var dict = x.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).SelectMany(s => s.Split('|')).ToDictionary(t => t.Split(',')[0], t => t.Split(',')[1]);

Answer (score 0):

Line breaks are typically used to indicate new records, like with CSV files. Really, any special character or sequence will do.